# finding h3 tag controls and setting inner text

Tags: asp.net

The header tag markup is shown below, it generates an id in page source like FeaturedContent_day3date

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" Runat="Server">
<div id="pagecontent">
<fieldset id="weeklyPnLGoals">
        <legend>Weekly PnL Targets with Actual for <%=DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM,   yyyy")%></legend>
            <div id="monthlywrapper" style="width:100%;">
                   <div id="firstweekwrapper" class="weekcontainer">
                        <div id="day1" class="daytile daytilefirst">
                            <h3 id="day1date" class="dateh3" runat="server"></h3><br />
                            <p id="day1equities"><span class="targettext"> <span   class="bluetext">Equities</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1equitytargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1equityactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day1options"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Options</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1optiontargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Options</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1optionactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day1futures"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1futuretargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1futureactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="day2" class="daytile">
                            <h3 id="day2date" class="dateh3" runat="server"></h3><br />
                            <p id="day2equities"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2equitytargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2equityactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day2options"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Options</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2optiontargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Options</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2optionactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day2futures"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2futuretargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2futureactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                        </div>
                         <div id="day3" class="daytile">
                            <h3 id="day3date" class="dateh3" runat="server"></h3><br />
                            <p id="day3equities"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3equitytargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3equityactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day3options"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Options</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3optiontargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Options</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3optionactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day3futures"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3futuretargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3futureactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                        </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim firstdate As DateTime = FirstTradingDayInMonth(DateTime.Now.Date)
    Dim dayofweeknumber As String = firstdate.Day.ToString()
    Dim tradingdaysthismonth As New List(Of Date)
    Dim tempDate As Date = firstdate
    Do While tempDate.Day < LastTradingDayInMonth(DateTime.Now.Date).Day

        If tempDate = firstdate Then
            tradingdaysthismonth.Add(tempDate)
            tempDate = AddBusinessDays(tempDate)
        Else
            tempDate = AddBusinessDays(tempDate)
            tradingdaysthismonth.Add(tempDate)
        End If
    Loop
    Dim h3Tags As New List(Of HtmlGenericControl)

    Dim h3Tagname As String = "day" & dayofweeknumber & "date"


    Dim htmlcontrol As HtmlGenericControl = TryCast(Me.Page.FindControl("firstweekwrapper").FindControl(h3Tagname), HtmlGenericControl)
    htmlcontrol.InnerText = firstdate.ToLongDateString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error that you posted, it would appear you're mixing c# string concatenation with vb string concatenation. This:

```
Dim h3Tagname As String = "FeaturedContent_day" + dayofweeknumber + "date"
```

Should be:

```
Dim h3Tagname As String = "FeaturedContent_day" & dayofweeknumber & "date"
```

This may not address the NullReferenceException, but it's at least a starting point.

**EDIT**

You need to find your `ContentPlaceHolder` first and this should help:

```
Dim cph As ContentPlaceHolder = TryCast(Master.FindControl("FeaturedContent"), ContentPlaceHolder)
Dim htmlcontrol As HtmlGenericControl = TryCast(cph.FindControl(h3Tagname), HtmlGenericControl)
```

Comment: incorrect, both versions yield day3date + works in vb.net as well as C#

Comment: Interesting. I get a conversion error when I use your version.

Comment: So this markup lies within a usercontrol called "FeaturedContent"? We're really grasping at straws here without any relevant code (aside from the markup)...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue is that FindControl does not permeate through naming containers. In other words, Me.Page.FindControl("firstweekwrapper") does not return the DIV, because Me.Page starts searching in the master page and when it gets to content place holders, it stops looking; thus null (Nothing).

Try this:

```
Dim FeaturedContent As ContentPlaceHolder = TryCast(Page.Master.FindControl("FeaturedContent"), ContentPlaceHolder)

Dim h3Tagname As String = "day" & dayofweeknumber & "date"

Dim htmlcontrol As HtmlGenericControl = TryCast(FeaturedContent.FindControl("firstweekwrapper").FindControl(h3Tagname), HtmlGenericControl)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 29:

```
Dim mainControl As HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("monthlywrapper")
```

In your markup, that DIV is not set to `runat="server"`, thus the server-side cannot "see" it.

Comment: asp.net 4.5 why, that shouldnt matter

Comment: Could you post more of your code, it would help in trying to resolve your problem?

Comment: ideally once i figure out how to get the one h3 ill loop thru those controls to set all the h3 tags, there are 22 or 23 on this page

Comment: I copied your code into a new project and it works fine to set the InnerText property of the dateh3 HTML control.  Are you trying to get to this control in the Page_Load event or somewhere else?  Also, off topic you are missing two closing DIV tags in your markup, this is not causing your issue, but just thought you might like to know.

Comment: i only copied you part of the code, i am doing this in the page load event. dateh3 is a class and doesnt identify a single tag. I need to create the tag im looking for by getting the day number of the month, ie 3 to make the tag day3date, thus the variable h3Tagname

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: your telling that to me? i have asked one question and have gotten minimal assistance from the respondent. I have not altered the question

Comment: @DaveS. I do not have the option to comment on his original post, therefore I answered the question by asking for clarification. I realize I was not answering his question, but I did not see any other way of getting information from him.  Sorry for not following protocol, but I did not have and still do not have the option to "comment" on his post.

Comment: Karl, dayofweeknumber is not null(Nothing in vb.net) as the h3Tagname is correct, day3date

Comment: Karl, I had it set to runat server before. I should be able to find the h3 tag id on its own within its naming container which is a contentplaceholder - "FeaturedContent" using FeaturedContent_day3date, which is how the id shows up in page source doesnt work either

Comment: firstweekwrapper is a DIV that is not marked as runat="server", if you change that does it work or same error?

Comment: having any of or all of the divs as runat server does nothing. the h3 tag should be accessible via findcontrol with its own id, but it isnt

Comment: I understand that Me.Page.FindControl(yourControlName) should find the control, but the code you posted makes reference to firstweekwrapper DIV in a FindControl call and then is chained with another call to FindControl for the dynamically built h3TagName string.  All I can go on is the code you posted.  Until you resolve the runat="server" for the firstweekwrapper FindControl call, then htmlControl is going to be null (Nothing in VB.NET).